# Searching in proximity to an area in Overpass

Tags: overpass-api

I'm trying to use overpass to find piers within "large" bodies of water. However, it seems like often piers are not inside water regions, but rather that the water curves around them. *Is it possible to search by proximity to an area? Or maybe there is an alternative approach?*

Here is a contrived example near Duluth, MN illustrating the issue.

We can look at piers (and bodies) of water within a bounding box:

```
[out:json][timeout:180];
(
  nwr(
    46.762191510926186,
    -92.08509489611468,                                                                                    
    46.76367911337914,  
    -92.08318778203628
  )["man_made"="pier"];
  wr["name"]["natural"="water"]["water"!="river"]["boat"!="no"](if: length() > 3000)(
    46.762191510926186,
    -92.08509489611468,                                                                                    
    46.76367911337914,  
    -92.08318778203628
  );
);
(._;>;);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Here we see that there is a body of water and several piers. However, if I alter the query so that the bodies of water in the bounding box are areas and then I search for piers within that area, I get an empty response:

```
[out:json][timeout:180];
area["name"]["natural"="water"]["water"!="river"]["boat"!="no"](if: length() > 3000)(
  46.762191510926186,
  -92.08509489611468,                                                                                    
  46.76367911337914,  
  -92.08318778203628
)->.mywater;
(
  nwr(area.mywater)["man_made"="pier"];
);
(._;>;);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

As mentioned above, it seems like the piers are not contained within the body of water, but rather sit on the boundary.

Comment: please inform us whether the answer below was working for you; that will validate the solution for people interested in the same thing in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, this works for me:

```
[out:json][timeout:180];
area[name="Lake Superior"];
way(area)["man_made"="pier"];
(._;>;);
out;
```

This query in Overpass Turbo: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1osL

Notes:

- Please have a look whether the list is complete. From your question it seems that you found a set of piers that "sit on the boundary" of the body of water. It might be useful if you published such examples.
- As you see, this is simplified version of your query: I limited it to Lake Superior, and only to piers mapped as ways. However, I believe you can expand it to other areas (using the bounding box in your original query) and piers mapped as nodes or relations.
- Alternatively, have a look at the `around` filter in [Overpass Query Language reference](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Relative_to_other_elements_(around)). I have good experience with searching around nodes; not sure how it works with areas.